# Why my charchter fluctuate instead go down stairs?

Tags: unity

My player is a capsule with:

- First person controller
- Charchter controller

When my player go up stairs, it works well. 
When my player go down stairs, it fluctuate in air.

What am i wrong ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say "fluctuate" ? I assume you are using `NavMesh` to handle moving around?

Comment: Maybe you should check your gravity settings

Comment: Fluctuate: flying .. it not touch terrain !

Comment: Are you using Unity's `NavMesh` ?

Comment: No i'm not using NavMesh. But in other projects i didn't need navmesh and my charachter correctly go up and down with the same controller.

Comment: Could you add an animated gif or something like that to your question to show what's going on?

Comment: I don't know Unity, but **Gravity multiplier** set to 0 seems like a pretty obvious cause for concern.

Comment: jack aidley: you're right thanks!

Comment: Great. I'll add that as an answer then.

Comment: @stighy judging from the comments, it sounds like the Jack's answer solved your problem - if so, don't forget to mark it as accepted & upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **Gravity Multiplier** set to 0, which is stopping gravity from applying to your character.